# Basis for a vector space with the derivative equaling a function

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to this site and am really rusty on my calculus. I have a homework question that is asking me to find the basis ($p(x)$ and $q(x)$) for a vector space of polynomials with degree less than $3$, satisfying $f'(7)=f(1)$.

I am totally lost. Can anyone explain how to even go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi needsalotofhelp, I've edited your post to use LaTeX markup.  You can see how everything was formatted by clicking the [edit] link below your question.  You can find more information on typesetting mathematics on [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/5531).  I've also added another tag, [tag:linear-algebra], to better classify your question.

Answer (score 1):

the vector space of all polynomials of degree less than $3$ is dimension $3$, given by the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2$ in 
$$
a_0 + a_1\cdot x + a_2 \cdot x^2
$$

The condition you gave is

$$
a_1 + 2\cdot a_2 \cdot 7 = a_0 + a_1\cdot 1 + a_2\cdot 1^2
$$

That gives you a linear equation in the $a_i$, and so you just need to find all $a_0,a_1,a_2$ that satisfy that linear equation, and give a basis ( which will necessarily be of size $2$ ).

Does that help?